# How to iterate all the child nodes and retrieve key value of all the childs in a ListView

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

```
public class PendingReqFragment extends android.app.Fragment {



public PendingReqFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.pending_req, container, false);
    return rootView;

}
```

I want to retrieve all the query name from all the child nodes of `sahil` node and display dynamically in the `ListView`.

Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdvCk.png) of the database.

```
{
    "query" : {
    "sahil" : [ null, {
      "address" : "bdbdbdb",
      "name" : "sahildeep",
      "no" : "64649",
      "pincode" : "373737",
      "query" : "hdbdbdvd",
      "user_name" : "sahil"
    }, {
      "address" : "zbxbbx",
      "name" : "sahil mehra",
      "no" : "949495",
      "pincode" : "1345",
      "query" : "snxbxb",
      "user_name" : "sahil"
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Also please show what you've already done. The Firebase Database documentation shows how to read from the database: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Comment: Yes I read the documentation knows the basic of retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a reference to the child in the database:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myPostReference = database.getReference("message").child("child1");
```

and then set ValueEventListener on that reference to get a DataSnapshot:

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
    Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    // Getting Post failed, log a message
    Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    // ...
}
};
mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

There's more detailed information in the Firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)